# Which one is the most natural in the eyes of a native speaker?

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, idiomatic-language

> She was an indescribably unique person.
>
> She was indescribably unique.
>
> Unexplainably(indefinably) unique. That’s how I’d describe her.

Initially I wrote as the first one, and then I thought 'A is a(n) ~ person' is a bit awkward, cause A is definetely a person, so I changed it to the second one.

But then again, what I want to emphasize here is that she is 'indescribably unique that it's hard to describe her', and in English we put the part we wanna emphasize at the beginning of the sentence. So I finally changed it to the third one. (I changed the adverb cause I have to repeat 'describe' if I use indescribably..)

But I thought it's unnecessary to divide the sentence in two, and I'm still not sure which one among those three is the most natural one in the eyes of native speakers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three are fine.  You're starting to get into questions of which is *good writing* rather than which is just acceptable grammar.  As with any language, there are many ways to organize the words in a sentence so that the sounds flow in a particular way, or to emphasize certain words.

Each of these means the same thing but *feels* different:

> She is very tall
>
> She is a very tall person
>
> I would describe her as "very tall"
>
> Tall. Very tall.  That's how I would describe her.

In this case, I would use *indefinably unique* rather than *indescribably unique*, because indefinable implies some kind of *mystery*, while *indescribable* simply means "I can't figure out which words to use".  Both are fine, but I think one sounds better than the other.

Again, this is the essence of *creative* writing, to pick the right words to convey your thoughts in an interesting way.